# How to merge two arays in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two arrays..

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
```

I want to merge these two arrays in such a way that result should look like this.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

One way is to add these two arrays and the call `uniq!` method.

```
c = a + b
c.uniq!
```

is there any shortcut method that I can do this in single call?

Comment: As JR Smith once said: "You trying to get the pipe?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not at my computer to confirm this, but I think you can use:

```
a | b
```

Which creates the union of the two arrays.

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-7C for the documentation.